# IOS parse HTML but get weird value "&#13;"

Tags: html, ios, parsing

Hi i'm doing my assignment and I want to get some information from this [website:](http://blogtruyen.com/truyen/conan). I used TFHpple.h from Raywenderlich [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) .Every thing went fine until I try to get the view count(this number: 8.024.835 ) but in my code it return this number `"&#13;"` I NSLOG its element.raw then I see this code:

```
<p>&#13;
        Số lượt xem: &#13;
        <span class="color-fuchsia" id="PageViews"/>    &#13;
&#13;
        Yêu thích:&#13;
        <span class="color-hotpink" id="LikeCount"/>&#13;
    </p>
```

but when I use firebug to its html, it display like this:

```
<p>
Số lượt xem:
<span id="PageViews" class="color-fuchsia">8.024.835</span>
     Yêu thích:
<span id="LikeCount" class="color-hotpink">1.565</span>
</p>
```

How to get the correct value please help me.

[image]

this is my code to parse and nslog the html.

```
-(void) GetBookViewCount{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@“http://blogtruyen.com/truyen/conan”];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];
    NSString* XpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='description']/p";
    NSArray *Nodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in Nodes) {
        NSLog(@"%@",element.raw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there a bunch of odd whitespace characters in between the two spans there.

```
&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;
```

This number here:

```
&#13;
```

Looks like an ascii code for a symbol (though I can't find one that matches), so when you parse the code it might be breaking when you hit those characters.  I'm not familiar with TFHpple.h but you may need to implement some input sanitization (stripping out those characters).